# Sonata Admin: how to change the final view of a field inside a form

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, custom-field-type

let's say I have a `Product` with `ManyToOne` relation with `Category` entity.
in the `configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)` of `ProductAdmin` we will do the following:

```
$formMapper->add('category');
```

And Sonata will render a `select` field.
But what I want to do is to customize the final view of the `select`, because I want to add some specific attributes to the `option` tags of the `select` (**not the select itself**).
I did this before in symfony by overriding the `finishView()` function inside the `FormType` like so:

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $field = 'category';
    $choices = $view->children[$field]->vars['choices'];
    foreach ($choices as $choice) {
        // I can add any attribute to the options like so
        $choice->attr['new-attribute'] = 'attribute_value';
    }
    $view->children[$field]->vars['choices'] = $choices;
}
```

But I can't find such function in `AbstractAdmin` provided by Sonata !
Is there a way to achieve this goal ?

Comment: You can use `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` to modify it before form rendering.

Comment: @ManojKumar thanks for your answer but this is used to modify data, but in my case I want to change the view (option tag), I want to add and extra attribute to it to render it in the form

Comment: you need https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr